# Ubuntu is Freezed when nvidia prime is switched to Performance Mode

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, gpu-driver, nvidia-geforce

I am using Ubuntu 22, which utilizes the X11 windowing system. My GPU is the GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile, and I have the Nvidia driver 530 open. However, when I switch to Nvidia Prime Performance Mode, my display freezes. How can I solve this issue?

My laptop model is ROG Strix G15